# How to prevent incorrect .js.coffee file from loading

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

In my rails app, it appears that all .js.coffee files are being loaded to each and every page, no matter what. The problem I have run into is that the locations.js.coffee file is being loaded and then returning a null value within a function because the table that the locations.js.coffee file is looking for does not exist on any other page that is not the locations page.

*Note: in each of the files: users.js.coffee, locations.js.coffee and campaigns.js.coffee I have placed the lines, respectively, console.log("users.coffee loaded"), console.log("locations.coffee loaded") and console.log("campaigns.coffee loaded") to see if they have loaded*

For example, refreshing the locations page yields a successful output to the console:

[image]

But venturing to the users or campaigns page will attempt to load the file locations.js.coffee, but since the table that locatrions.js.coffee depends on with id `#restaurantLocations` does not exist in users or campaigns, the resultant error is:

[image]

For the line: `table.columns().eq(0).each (colIdx)` in the file locations.js.coffee.

**How can I prevent this error or only permit the correct file to be loaded for the correct page and prevent the others from loading?**

(Remaining locations.js.coffee code):

```
jQuery ->
  console.log("locations.coffee loaded")

  # Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
  $("#restaurantLocations tfoot th").each ->
    title = $("#restaurantLocations thead th").eq($(this).index()).text()
    $(this).html "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Search " + title + "\" />"

  # DataTable
  table = $("#restaurantLocations").DataTable()

    # Apply the search
  table.columns().eq(0).each (colIdx) ->
    $("input", table.column(colIdx).footer()).on "keyup change", ->
      table.column(colIdx).search(@value).draw()

  # Hiding the id column, but for use for data manipulation
  table.column( 0 ).visible( false )

  # Allowing multi-select
  $("#restaurantLocations tbody").on "click", "tr", ->
    $(this).toggleClass "selected"

  # Allowing deletion (works)
  $("#deleteLocations").click ->
    multiSelected = table.rows(".selected").data()
    table.rows(".selected").remove().draw false
    for locationSelected in multiSelected
      id = locationSelected[0]
      $.ajax({
        url: "/locations/" + id,     # Note: $.ajax setup works as setting /locations/(id number) will allow deletion
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"_method":"delete"}
      })

  # Conditional 'Select All' (works)
  $("#selectAllLocations").click ->
    table.$('tr', {"filter":"applied"}).addClass "selected"

  # Deselecting all (works)
  $("#deSelectAllLocations").click ->
    table.$("tr").removeClass "selected"
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Rails includes a file at `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` that requires all other files in `app/assets/javascripts`. Then, the default application layout includes that file.

There are other ways to organize your assets, including [controller-specific assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets). These require customizing your assets configuration.

However, I don't recommend this. It is much better if you can write your JavaScript in such a way that it can be included on every page, and simply does not execute anything on pages where it isn't needed.

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this: one simple one is to use jQuery to look for a particular class on the page body, or somewhere else on the page.

In the code above, all you would need to do is wrap `if $("#restaurantLocations").length > 0` around the whole thing (but inside the `jQuery` callback function).

This gives you a few benefits:

- It is a simpler configuration, sticking with the Rails default conventions, and easier to understand.
- It is more resilient to changes in your app. If you need to use that JavaScript on a new page, or stop needing it on an existing page, you only need to add or remove the relevant class (or whatever markup you're searching for), and not fuss with your script tags or the require statements in your asset manifests.
- It avoids duplication. If the scripts on different pages share common dependencies, you'll need to require them in both of the top-level scripts.
- It is better for users, since after assets are precompiled, you'll end up with a single concatenated and compressed file used on every page in your app. Users will only have to download this once, and then when navigating to other pages, it will be loaded out of the cache. Unless there is a large amount of JavaScript that is confined to pages that most users never visit, it is more efficient to combine everything.

Read [The Asset Pipeline Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for details on how assets work in Rails.

Comment: the only thing I'd add to this answer is that if you are doing it with a gigantic document.ready function, you're probably doing it wrong. +1